# Is standing and raising hands an usual posture for praying?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Is standing and raising hands an usual posture for praying?
I wonder which is the right posture for praying.

Comment: see Kings 1:8:22

Comment: Although we find moshe rabainu lifted up his hands and others we do not do this today. I think it is a tshuva in beer sheva.

Comment: ו. ובשו"ת באר שבע סי' עא' איתא וז"ל:
מנעורי תמהתי למה אין אנו נוהגים להתפלל
בזקיפת ידים למעלה כמו שנהגו אבותינו
מעולם, כמו שנאמר הרמותי ידי אל ה' עליון
וגו' ותרגם אונקלוס ארימית ידי בצלו קדם ה'
ו

Comment: http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/526_44_80_0.pdf

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.95.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that ideally one should place his hands on his heart, with the left hand underneath the right hand. However the [Aruch HaShulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.91.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that it depends on the individual - you may find it easier to pray with your hands elsewhere. Each individual can determine what hand position helps him pray better.